# Вычислить координаты точки по координатам другой системы

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!

Есть 2 точки разных систем координат, и базис у систем координат не совпадает по направлению, то есть оси не сонаправлены.

Хочу спросить, как преобразовать координаты одной системы в другую на плоскости.

Первая система точка 1
x: 1145.3550360137756
y: 333.8363648366939

Вторая система точка 1
{ "x": -97.41582552225863, "y": 19.703228790630007, } }

Первая система точка 2
x: 1245.4066162357462
y: 448.1973298138752

Вторая система точка 2
"position": { "x": -72.55720999714077, "y": 20.21850089264507, } }

Я хочу по координатам точки первой системы можно было находить координаты той же точки второй системы

Я так понимаю нужно найти некий коэффициент и от него плясать, хелп плиз

Comment: Добро пожаловать! У первой системы есть название? Какой это формат для координат? Думаю, что коэффициент не поможет в данном случае, поскольку координаты это значения, которые учитывают углы через тригонометрические функции.

Comment: Чтобы преобразовать координаты точек нужны базисы обеих систем.

Comment: Без базисов по двум точкам на плоскости отображение восстанавливается неоднозначно.

Comment: Системы все кастомные. Просто есть точка на одном плане и нужно ее же отобразить на другом.
Восстанавливать однозначно и не требуется.